# How to add conditional in string?

Tags: sql-server, t-sql

I need to test for a condition within a string.  I'm using a simple condition below just to make the example easy to work with.  But even this simple example doesn't work once the condition is added.  What am I doing wrong?

```
SELECT '<p><input type="checkbox" name_' + CAST(mt.personid AS VARCHAR) +
  CASE WHEN 1=1 THEN
  'checked' +
  END
  '></p>' AS MyContent
from mytable mt
```

Error:

```
Incorrect syntax near the keyword 'END'
```

If I remove the plus after 'checked', I get:

```
Incorrect syntax near the keyword 'AS'
```

Comment: you are not ending your `CASE` expression?, `CASE WHEN condition THEN something [ELSE] somethingelse END`. Also, don't use `CAST` to a varchar without specifying the length. Also, what does "doesn't work" means here?, what exactly happens?

Comment: Well, you have `'checked' + END`, the plus sign there is wrong, it should be `'checked' END +`

Comment: But now you removed the plus sign after the `END`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this.

```
SELECT '<p><input type="checkbox" name_' + CAST(mt.personid AS VARCHAR) +
  isnull(
  CASE 
    WHEN 1=1 THEN 'checked'
  END, '')
  +
  '></p>'
from mytable mt
```

Or this (credits to @Lamak):

```
SELECT '<p><input type="checkbox" name_' + CAST(mt.personid AS VARCHAR) +
  CASE 
    WHEN 1=1 THEN 'checked'
    ELSE ''
  END
  +
  '></p>'
from mytable mt
```

Comment: Yes - that does work.  But if you try the fail condition of 1=2, you get null output.  It should output the content without 'checked'.  At least that is what I'd like.  Any idea how to accomplish that?

Comment: @4thSpace `ELSE '' END`